# How to use md-dialog in your own Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular2-material

A simple question with a hopefully a simple answer: I have been trying to add dialog from @angular2-material to my own project, but so far my attempts with just copying the node-modules/@angular2-material files to my project's node-modules directory have failed.

I have successfully installed core, button and so on using npm, but attempts to use dialog has failed. If I try to use demo-dialog app files as a proof-of-concept I only get to "Loading...", so the component is never instantiated correctly.

What is the approach I should use? The stage-release script, publish to a local NPM repository, ... ?

Comment: If you are getting a screen that says `Loading...` and it ends there then you typically have an error in the Javascript console.  Can you open the developer tools in your browser and take a look at the console and see if there is an error message?

Comment: Also, how are you starting your project?  The angular quickstart? angular-cli? webpack?  Some sort of seed project?  The method for installing and configuring your modules will depend on what approach you are taking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments from [Pace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202694/pace) I managed to figure out the approach:

1. (material2 project) Use the stage-script in the script/release folder to create a deploy folder with almost-ready-to-deploy components
2. copy the `package.json` file from the button component and change button to dialog
3. go to your project and do a `npm install folder-path-to-material2-deploy-component` for at least `core` and `dialog`
4. If you use angular-cli make sure you have updated files as described here: [Angular-cli wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs#adding-material2-to-your-project) I prefer the approach with a `materialPkgs.forEach` as you can see here: [example file](https://github.com/kara/puppy-love-io/blob/master/src/system-config.ts) instead of step 4 on the Angular-cli wiki page, but it doesn't matter. 
   Just note that (at least my out of the box project did) there are two system-config.ts files, so if you see 404s when you open your More Tools->Developer Tools->Console you updated the wrong one.

Now you can start to add the imports and directives you need to do your template definition.

Lars